# When to use a ROS service rather than a normal node

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
I am new to ROS services, I have been working with ROS nodes and topics but I never needed to use services. When looking through the tutorials I didn't fully understand what is the difference between a service and a normal nodes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283305/when-to-use-a-ros-service-rather-than-a-normal-node/) by [Mostafa Osman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33507/mostafa-osman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2018-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-21**:
Please see #q11834 which has very good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I didn't fully understand what is the difference between a service and a normal nodes

They are different concepts.

Trying to simplify I would say that the service can be seen as function or procedure call, i.e., you call a service for performing one task and obtaining (or not) a result.

---

Originally posted by [hector.herrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/18916/hector.herrero/) with karma: 36 on 2018-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2